# First five terms of power series

Tags: calculus, power-series, formal-power-series

I want to find first $5$ terms for power series of $\frac{1 - x + 2 x^2}{1 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^6}$.

$a_0 = \frac{1 - x + 2 x^2}{1 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^6} (0)$ = 1

$a_1 = \frac{\partial \frac{1 - x + 2 x^2}{1 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^6}}{\partial x}(0)$ = $-1$

$a_2 = \frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2 \frac{1 - x + 2 x^2}{1 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^6}}{\partial x^2}(0)$ = $7$

$a_3 = \frac{1}{3!}\frac{\partial^3 \frac{1 - x + 2 x^2}{1 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^6}}{\partial x^3}(0)$ = $-5$

$a_4 = \frac{1}{4!}\frac{\partial^4 \frac{1 - x + 2 x^2}{1 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^6}}{\partial x^4}(0)$ = $35$

It is true?

Does more simple solution exists?

Comment: A bit simpler to write $1-x+2x^2=(1-5x^3+3x^6)(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\cdots)$ and expand the RHS up to $c_4$

Comment: We really don't want  to compute so many derivatives, or indeed any. An awful  lot  of work, high probability of error.  I would expand $(1-(5x^3-3x^6))^{-1}$  using the power series expansion of $(1-t)^{-1}$. We hardly need any terms, for almost immediately we get too high powers of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

To get the series
up to $x^5$:

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1 - x + 2 x^2}{1 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^6}
&=(1 - x + 2 x^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (5 x^3 - 3 x^6)^n\\
&=(1 - x + 2 x^2)(1+(5 x^3 - 3 x^6)+...)\\
&=(1 - x + 2 x^2)(1+5 x^3 )\\
&=(1 - x + 2 x^2)+(5x^3 - 5x^4 + 10 x^5)\\
&=1 - x + 2 x^2+5x^3 - 5x^4 + 10 x^5\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks!

But why does my answer not equal your answer?

Wolfram Alpha gives my terms http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+-x+%2B+2+x%5E2%29%2F%281+-+5+x%5E2+%2B+3+x%5E6%29